# Inverse image of a closed interval is a disjoint union of closed intervals

Tags: general-topology

Assume $g \colon \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function. Could someone point me in the right direction of the proof, that for all $u\in \mathbb{R}$ there exist $a_i,b_i$, one $a_i$ possibly $-\infty$ and one $b_i$ possibly $\infty$, s.t.

$
g^{-1}(-\infty, u] = \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty [a_i,b_i]
$

with disjoint $[a_i,b_i]$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $C\subset [0,1]$ be the Cantor set, and define $f(x) = \inf_{c \in C} |x-c|$. The function $f$ is continuous and since $C$ is closed we have $f(x) = 0$ **iff** $c \in C$.

We have $C = f^{-1} (-\infty,0]$. The set $C$ contains no interval of non-zero length (since $m C = 1$) and is uncountable.

Hence $f^{-1} (-\infty,0]$ cannot be written in the form $\cup_{i=1}^\infty [a_i,b_i]$ (since we would need to have $a_i = b_i$ and this would imply that $C$ was countable).